# Represent a process flow diagram in a pandas dataframe with sequence information

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, dataframe, data-analysis

I'm trying to represent a process flow diagram in a pandas dataframe. Let me give you an example let's say we've a process diagram like this -
Proces Diagram:-

[image]

Please have a look at the image. Now, I've created pandas dataframe based on the information in the image -

| process name | Id | To Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| process 1 | 10 | 200 |
| process 1 | 10 | 80 |
| process 2 | 200 | 8 |
| process 3 | 80 | NAN |
| process 4 | 8 | 70 |
| process 5 | 70 | NAN |

You guy's can generate the above dataframe by->

```py
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'process name': {0: 'process 1',
  1: 'process 1',
  2: 'process 2',
  3: 'process 3',
  4: 'process 4',
  5: 'process 5'},
 'Id': {0: 10, 1: 10, 2: 200, 3: 80, 4: 8, 5: 70},
 'To Id': {0: 200, 1: 80, 2: 8, 3: None, 4: 70, 5: None}})
```

I want to add one more information column that is sequence like this -

| process name | Id | To Id | Sequence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Start | 0 | 10 | 0 |
| process 1 | 10 | 200 | 1 |
| process 1 | 10 | 80 | 1 |
| process 2 | 200 | 8 | 2 |
| process 3 | 80 | NAN | 2 |
| process 4 | 8 | 70 | 3 |
| process 5 | 70 | NAN | 4 |

Here, I've created an additional row with process name start(sequence 0) which represent the start of my diagram(`id =0` and `To Id=10`).
The sequence algorithm then checks for 10 in id column and there are 2 matches. So ,it'll mark those rows as 1 and store there `to ID` information.
Again it'll pick 1 "to ID" from [200,80]. Let's say 80 then it'll repeat the same process and mark the row starting with 80 as sequence 2 and here the `To Id` is NAN so the process will stop and it'll check for `To ID` 200.

Is there any easy way to add this sequence column information fast? any good algorithm?.

I can extract the first row using set diff. like this -

```
id =  set(df['Id'].to_list())
to_id = set(df['To Id'].to_list()) 
id - to_id #will give output 10 which is our start point.
```

I need help from here onwards how can I achieve sequence column from here?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit and show the piece of code you wrote yet about your trial to solve this problem, so we can reproduce and help you answer the question.
See MRE here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming no step has 2, or more parents (which is necessary condition to have unique sequence identification):

```py
# this has to be defined *after* df_2 initialisation
def count_prev(curr) -> int:
    new = df_2.loc[df_2['To Id'].eq(curr), 'Id']
    if(len(new)>0):
        return count_prev(new.iloc[0]) + 1
    return 1
    
df_2['Sequence'] = df_2['Id'].agg(count_prev)
```

Result:

```py
  process name   Id  To Id  Sequence
0    process 1   10  200.0         1
1    process 1   10   80.0         1
2    process 2  200    8.0         2
3    process 3   80    NaN         2
4    process 4    8   70.0         3
5    process 5   70    NaN         4
```

Comment: The key's in dictionary are dynamic. I can't just hardcode the sequence via this method. I need some algorithm to add the sequence based on two columns "Id" and "To Id".

Comment: @PrakharGupta try now